# How many clients are connected to specified port number

Tags: client, freebsd, ports

How can I count all connections (clients) that are connected to the specified port on my (remote) server?

Lets say port number is gonna be: `3306` (MySQL port), so how to count how many clients are connected to this port during the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look, I know I'd do this in linux:
`netstat -anp | grep ":3306.*ESTABLISHED" | wc -l`

I expect it to work in FreeBSD as well.... let me know the result!

Comment: Here are the results: `# netstat -anp | grep ":3306.*ESTABLISHED" | wc -l
netstat: option requires an argument -- p` Seems like my netstat doesn't support `p`.

Comment: Ok, just remove the "p" from the netstat's arguments... i.e: `netstat -an | grep ":3306.*ESTABLISHED" | wc -l`

Comment: The idea is: Try playing with netstat's parameters and get the ones you need that shows you "ESTABLISHED" TCP connections. The rest (grep and wc) should be the same.

Comment: @Poni - Note that the `| wc -l` part is redundant; you can add a `-c` option to `grep` to save yourself some plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

1. my os is freebsd 12.2 version
2. chang your ip address in /usr/local/etc/mysql/my.conf
3. edit data at line bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to your ip address ex.192.168.1.2
4. restart your server
5. check your result by netstat -an
6. I hope see you happy.